# How to remove sticky navbar while on mobile mode?

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, sticky

I have a problem to remove a sticky navbar stuff while on mobile mode. Please help me how to make it not sticky while on mobile mode, please. And this is my JavaScript that I made for the sticky navbar. I gave the navbar ID = 'navbar'.

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else if (window.pageYOffset <= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    } else if (window.pageYOffset.innerWidth < 360) {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Comment: Just  use a media query.  You don't need JS for this unless `sticky` is a library class.